# Native Java to Android Java (JsonPath)

Tags: java, jsonpath

I'm converting native Java code to android one.
There is a Android Java code from a native Java as following:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
...
body = new String(bodyPart);
JsonPath.with(body).getString("psIp");
...
```

However, there is no with method in Android. How can I convert it?

Answer (score 1):

JsonPath class comes from some library (most likely `'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.8.1'`), which has `com.jayway.jsonpath`package. This class is not present neither in native Java, nor in native Android.

You have a dependency to that library, that has JsonPath class, in your Java project (anyway you added it - either through gradle, maven, or simply by adding a reference to jar file through IDE). If you would add that dependency to your Android project (gradle is preferred for adding dependencies in Android, though you can add it any other way), you will be able to use JsonPath class in your Android code also.

Comment: My previous dependency is incorrect. "compile group: 'com.jayway.restassured', name: 'json-path', version: '2.9.0'
" is correct.